# Unable to authenticate to Lion Server on development machine

Tags: osx-server

I have a Lion Server machine which was upgraded from Snow Leopard Server and is my main development machine as well. When I open the Server app, and select "This Mac - pro1" to manage services I am asked to authenticate with an Administrator Name and password. Since I am an Admin on my machine I used my Username and Password, yet when I select "Connect" button it shakes and denies me access.

I am at a loss as to how to proceed. I am not sure if there is a number of retries limit I have exceeded, but doing everything including restarting the Mac still leaves me unable to authenticate to the Server app even though I am obviously logged in as myself. Any advice on how to diagnose this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3960

When I looked at my servermgrd.plist I saw that Disabled key was set to true. Changed it to false, saved and reloaded the plist. Now I can log in as myself. Only mystery is how it got set that way. I am running 10.7.4 which theoretically should not have that respective problem.